# android 5.1.x security settings missing after upgrade

Tags: security, 5.1-lollipop, operating-system

A friend of mine asked me for help, she currently uses a Samsung phone with android 5.1.1 and misses settings for virus security and cpu in the main settings UI. The "virus" alert should be something with red/yellow/green indicators, she said. Also there should be some settings concerning the operationg system. 
The change happened during an upgrade I guess.

I cannot figure out what she is speaking about, I have been using a Galaxy 2 and 4 up to now, currently running with 5.0.1

Do you have any idea what I could search for?

I also like to ask if you know an app (no root) for these security issues!?

Comment: App is not perhaps available. Tell her to try and run software update again. If some files couldn't be installed, t get might be installed. Otherwise it's best to take the phone to a service centre.

Comment: I think you're referring to smart manager, I'll try put a solution and advise me if addresses your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What she meant were the developer options, the overlay where system stuff is showm in the upper right...

Answer (score 1):

Based on on description, I think you might be referring to Samsung's Smart Manger. Smart manager gives an overview of the device's RAM, Battery, Clean up as well as Security (contains sn anti-malware engine).

> Smart Manager's functions are to manage storage and RAM, scan and
>   optimize data usage to preserve battery levels, and protect from
>   security threats, close all apps running in the background that
>   significantly drain the battery, uninstall unneeded applications, and
>   run malware scans.

See below:

[image]

It is most likely the OS update didn't have Smart Manager. However the good thing is [Smart Manager has been renamed Device Maintenance](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/06/03/samsung-uploads-device-maintenance-tool-play-store/) and is available [from Google Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.lool&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Ddevice%20maintenance%20samsung&pcampaignid=APPU_1_aISNWd_eBIGCgAbavpfYAw) as long the device is compatible

Comment: Thank for this suggestion/answer. I find it helpful for me personally, though it is not that setting my friend meant.